# Laravel, Cannot get simple hasMany relationship to return results

Tags: laravel, relationship

I am trying to run a really simple model with relationship eloquent query. My code is below and as you can see, I am just outputting the results to the page for now:

ServiceController.php

```php
    class ServiceController extends Controller
    {
        public function show(string $id): JsonResponse
        {
            $services = Service::with('transactions')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($services->toArray());
            echo '</pre>';
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Service.php

```php
    class Service extends Model
    {
        public function transactions()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
        }
    }
```

My transactions database tables contains the following columns:

*transactions*

| id | ... | service_id | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at |

I get no error when I run this, but the transactions relationship is empty. *But only for some results*. Some services have all the transactions returned correctly. Some have them missing.

What am I doing wrong?  It seems a simple setup. Surely I can't be missing something so big?

**Edit**
I have noticed that the missing relationship all belong to the same two services. All services return their transactions correctly except for these two services. Not sure if that means anything.

Comment: did you check the deleted_at? maybe some are soft deleted.

Comment: All 'deleted_at' values are null.

Comment: So, frustrated, I ran my migrations again with the fresh and seed flags.  The two services that were not showing relationships are now working. However, three other services - which were previously working - are now not. It seems every time I run a fresh migration/seed, random services break their relationships. I have never seen this before. Does anyone else have any ideas? I am using a hosted mysql database with A2 Hosting. I have never had problems with them in the past.